# Why this code can't set background color from main contents to bottom

Tags: html, css, background-color

I wrote this code.
This code is html and css.

```
...

#contents
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border-top: 3px solid black;
    background-image: url(img/CloverImage.png);
    background-size: 300px 400px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#content
{
    margin: auto;
    padding: 50px;
    width: 860px;
    height: auto;
    color: black;
}

...

<div id="contents">
<div id="content">
<p id="title">What are we making?</p>
<div id="mainapp">
    <h1>Pegasus</h1>
    Pegasus is very useful wordpress poster application.<br>
    This app can input html tags easily.<br>
    We're making it to open to the public.
</div>
<div id="subapp1">
    <h1>A to Z</h1>
    HAHAHAHA
</div>
<div id="subapp2">
    <h1>A to Z</h1>
    HEHEHEHE
</div>
</div>
</div>

...
```

I want to set background color from main contents to bottom.

But this code can't do it.

This is the site.

http://www.clover.lrv.jp

Tell me a solution to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a clearfix, or a clear class to handle the float behavior

Clear class

HTML

```
<div id="content">
    <p id="title">What are we making?</p>
    <div id="mainapp"> 
        <h1>Pegasus</h1>
        Pegasus is very useful wordpress poster application.<br>
        This app can input html tags easily.<br>
        We're making it to open to the public.
    </div>
    <div id="subapp1">
        <h1>A to Z</h1>
        HAHAHAHA
    </div>
    <div id="subapp2">
        <h1>A to Z</h1>
        HEHEHEHE
    </div>
    <div class="cb"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.cb{
    clear:both;
}
```

---

OR with the clearfix class ( based on the html5 boilerplate )

HTML

```
<div id="content" class="clearfix">
    <p id="title">What are we making?</p>
```

CSS

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after{
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
clearfix:after{
    clear: both;
}
/* * For IE 6/7 only * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats. */
.clearfix {
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

There are a lot of other ways to clear floats, but, I hope you get the concept.

You can find more information about floats and clearing floats on these places:

**Mozilla Developer Network**
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float

**WebPlatform**
http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/css/properties/clear

**Micro clearfix [html5 boilerplate uses it]**
http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the `<div id="contents">` element in Chrome devtools you will see that it's dimensions are not expanding with its children, which usually occurs when it contains floats that are not being cleared by that parent element.

So you're options are to use one of the many clearfixing solutions out there.

The simplest is to add `overflow: hidden` to the CSS of the `#contents` element.

**CSS**

```
#contents { overflow: hidden; }
```

More advanced and robust solution you can re-use throughout your template is the micro-clearfix invented by [Nicolas Gallagher](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/), which sensibly places the clearfix in a class which you would add to the HTML markup.

**CSS**

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}

.clearfix {
  *zoom: 1;
}
```

I have not tested these across browsers, but they work in chrome and should work for you.